# Nested tab bar in Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there a way in Ionic framework to have a nested tab bar like this:

[image]

I tried it in Codepen, but it doesn't really work:

[Example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/Glitchbone/pen/GEcae)

```
.state('tabs.about', {
    url: "/about",
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'about-tab': {
            templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
        }
    }
})

.state('tabs.about.page1', {
    url: "/page1",
    views: {
        'about-page1': {
            templateUrl: "templates/about-page1.html"
        }
    }
})

.state('tabs.about.page2', {
    url: "/page2",
    views: {
        'about-page2': {
            templateUrl: "templates/about-page2.html"
        }
    }
});
```

Is there someone who knows the proper way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I try to example at codePen but I doesn't work as I expected. But I solved your problem in a local project. Be sure you have the last version of ionic or you can update it with:

```
npm install -g ionic
```

You are almost there. You need to set a abstract into the views like this:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

.state('tabs', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
})

.state('tabs.home', {
    url: "/home",
    views: {
        'home-tab': {
            templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
        }
    }
})

.state('tabs.about', {
    url: "/about",        
    views: {
        'about-tab': {
            templateUrl: "templates/about.html",
            abstract: true
        }
    }
})

.state('tabs.about.page1', {
    url: "/page1",
    views: {
        'about-page1': {
            templateUrl: "templates/about-page1.html"
        }
    }
})

.state('tabs.about.page2', {
    url: "/page2",
    views: {
        'about-page2': {
            templateUrl: "templates/about-page2.html"
        }
    }
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

});
```

And using the code that you had commented:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-stable">

             <ion-tab title="Page 1" ui-sref="tabs.about.page1">
               <ion-nav-view name="about-page1"></ion-nav-view>
             </ion-tab>

             <ion-tab title="Page 2" ui-sref="tabs.about.page2">
                 <ion-nav-view name="about-page2"></ion-nav-view>
             </ion-tab>

         </ion-tabs>
```

I comment the previous tab code, specifically this:

```
<!--<div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-stable">
         <div class="tabs">
           <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="tabs.about.page1">
             Page 1
           </a>
           <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="tabs.about.page2">
             Page 2
           </a>
         </div>
       </div>-->
```

The rest of the HTML code is the same

My ionic version is: 1.3.19

I hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks buddy. Saved my day! I was also following OPs method. I have one problem. How can I prevent going back when accessed the URL directly, say: http://localhost:8100/#/tabs/7/live/messages ? can I ask seperately?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. But you can override the behavior of the back button.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionNavBackButton/

You add the markup in your view and add the onClick function to your controller. That will always trigger that function instead of normal back button behavior.

Hope it helps!